# Make Command Won't Link FFMpeg

Tags: macos, cmake, ffmpeg, libav

I am trying to install FFMpeg and I am using a Mac.

I keep getting

```
archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '[The path to the directory]/libavdevice/libavdevice.a'
```

And there is one for each libav folder.

I am running the following commands

```
git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local
make
```

I'm not too sure what I should be expecting, but an error is definitely not it

-- edit --

I have also tried with FFMpeg version 3.0. And I got the same error

Comment: Why not `brew install ffmpeg`?

Comment: So I did ```brew install ffmpeg``` however it didn't include all the header files I expected. I have since found out that I don't need the other header files. But I am still curious why I can't build it myself, hence keeping the question open

Comment: You want to use `ffmpeg` as a library?  I think you need `libavcodec` and `libavformat` instead.

Comment: And I believe those are included inside ffmpeg, when it's installed? If not how do I just install those?

Comment: Have you followed [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS)?  Configuring with `configure --disable-programs` looks like it might work.

Comment: Wow wow, yes that's worked! How did you find --disable-programs? I can't find it anywhere on the page you linked? I must be being very blind, but thank you very much!

Comment: I found it on another SO question about compiling the libraries.